# Plain Preformatted Text Styling with Line Numbers Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a preformatted text generated and trying to style it without using any syntax highlighter and using a simple JavaScript. But it breaks in responsive mode.

If you check the `.code-inner` contains a width 80% but still it acquires the fullwidth. Is that something overfloating with `overflow: auto;` or did I added any code which seems to be wrong.

```js
function preformatted() {
var pre = document.getElementsByTagName('pre'), pl = pre.length;
if(jQuery(pre).find('.line-number').length){
  return;
}
for (var i = 0; i < pl; i++) {
  pre[i].innerHTML = '<span class="line-number"></span>' + pre[i].innerHTML + '<span class="cl"></span>';
  var num = pre[i].innerHTML.split(/\n/).length;
  for (var j = 0; j < num; j++) {
    var line_num = pre[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
    line_num.innerHTML += '<span>' + (j + 1) + '</span>';
  }
}
}

preformatted();
```

```css
.code-inner {
position: relative;
width: 80%;
}

pre {
  overflow:auto;
  margin:0 0 1em;
  padding:.5em 2em;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
.code-wrap {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #264567 60px, #73b9ff 0% 80%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 18px -7px #000;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
pre code,
pre .line-number {
  font:normal normal 16px/14px Lato, "Courier New",Courier,Monospace;
  color:black;
  display:block;
    line-height: 30px;
}

pre .line-number {
  float:left;
  margin:0 1em 0 -1em;
  text-align:right;
    color:#fff;
}

pre .line-number span {
  display:block;
  padding:0 .5em 0 1em;
}

pre .cl {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}

/* Vertical Scroll */
.code-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 4px;
}

/* Track */
.code-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
.code-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #fff;
    border-right: 4px #555555 solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="code-inner">
<div class="code-wrap">
<pre>
<code>
° Vivamus feugiat quam sed ipsum varius aliquam.
° In ac augue eu leo dignissim cursus hendrerit sed nulla.
° Sed dapibus justo id lectus rhoncus pulvinar.
° Aliquam sit amet enim ut nisl gravida lobortis.
° Nunc a sapien non lorem mollis viverra.
° Donec feugiat nunc quis condimentum feugiat.
</code>
</pre>
</div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are setting the width of `.code-wrap` 2 places, first at `width: 80%;` and then later at `width: 100%;`

Comment: Fixed the class name and solved, the other issue is when responsive the code line numbers and code lines.

Comment: Just check this https://jsfiddle.net/qunzorez/qxurvnw8/20/ did is correct?

Comment: Thanks for your response the solution was helpfull the question was also  helpfull